# Directed graph editor d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have to use Directed Graph Editor `(http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)` in Internet Explorer 9. Its not working properly in IE 9 and above. There are issues with edges between nodes. I have mentioned its link. You can open the same in IE9. The edges are rendered but are distorted and are invisible at times. I have used Aight.js but it didn't work. Kindly help.

Comment: please include image or show what and where isn't working